# Why are communism and anarcho-communism not seen as extreme-reactionary?

Tags: ideology, communism, conservatism, liberalism, anarchism

### Context

It is a common usage to call some right-wing movements in Western countries "reactionary". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionary):

> In ideology, reactionism is a tradition in right-wing politics

Reactionary is defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionary) in this way:

> In political science, a reactionary or a reactionist is a person who holds political views that favor **a return to the *status quo ante*, the previous political state of society**, which that person believes possessed positive characteristics absent from contemporary society.

Although it can be meant as an insult, sometimes it is not, and some right-wing figures even openly recognize themselves as "reactionary". This is the case of the French far-right political figure Éric Zemmour. He, as a self-described nostalgic reactionary, wants to go back to the old France (as of which French period, see the debates in comments). In general though, if I am not mistaken, European (reactionary) far-rights hold high the values of the pre-Enlightenment Europe, and want to come back to something near to this period, which sure enough they may fantasize.

### Question

If some right-wing ideologies are reactionary, why are communism (Engels and Marx) and anarcho-communism (Bakunin, Proudhon, Kropotkin) not seen, by the general public and the media globally, as reactionary too, in their case extreme-reactionary?

Indeed, they want to go back to the hunter-gatherers kind of society. Marx and Engels coined the notion of "primitive-communism", a state which our society should go back to. The French anarcho-communist Pierre Clastres was also clear about it ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communisme_libertaire)):

> Some, like Pierre Clastres, consider that the organization of certain traditional non-Western societies (such as the Guayaki) in different parts of the world (the Americas, Africa, Asia, Polynesia), which have lasted for millennia, are at least partly similar to anarcho-communism.

### Hypothesis

I would say this is because they stress on something modern: communism emphasizes the preliminary phase of the people dictatorship, and anarcho-communism emphasizes the masses revolutionary struggles. Yet, this is not their project per se, only the means towards their project.

Comment: Not seen as reactionary by whom? Some on the right certainly see communism as an old discredited ideology. There's also a lot of different types of communism - classical Marxism was heavily focused on historical progress and mechanisation as a precursor of post-scarcity utopian communism. I also imagine you'd find some aspects of anarcho-communism and communal living described as reactionary by Marxists, as some Marxists call anything they disagree with reactionary and counter-revolutionary. Do you want a history of what people call "reactionary"?

Comment: @StuartF Thanks for the question (edited my post. Also see the quotation from Wikipedia). I mean by the general public, in general

Comment: Observing that traditional societies are organised along anarcho-communist lines is not the same as advocating anarcho-primitivism. It's just noticing a similarity in political organisation. Not at all the same as advocating for returning to a level of prior technological development. You are equivocating communism with anarcho primitivism, which are completely different ideologies. Your claim that "they [all communists] want to go back to the hunter-gatherers kind of society" is simply incorrect.

Comment: I would point out @Starckman that you might get better answers if you specified that the people you believe do not see them as reactionary were historians or a relatively political-science oriented source.

Comment: @AntiElonGuy thanks for your comment. Historians may participate in forming the general opinion, but they are maybe not the only source. Media, politicians, laypeople, etc. can all participate in forming this general opinion

Comment: First is reactionary often used a negative pejorative? I believe that it usually is... In that case I recommend you look at who controls the media. That should explain why people on the right are reactionary old fudy duds who are being misled by evil giant corporations who don't know better. and people on the left are hip and cool rebels that are making the world a better place.

Comment: *"European far-rights hold high the values of the middle-ages"* what the hell? Do you have any kind of source for that? What does that sentence even mean, actually?

Comment: "Indeed, they want to go back to the hunter-gatherers kind of society." -> vote to close due to obvious lack of prior research...

Comment: Agreed with @user4688 about the phrasing : Zemmour is typically nostalgic of the colonial France (before 1962, the independance of Algeria), and while the ideas of far right parties on security and immigration are stuck in the 1900s, they usually have more progressive policies on economic and social issues than "traditional" right parties

Comment: @Aserre The context here was the reactionary, so I did not have in mind big political parties such as the National Rally, which, in order to be successful, abandoned the controversial rhetoric based on identity, and focused on, as you pointed, economic and security issues. I suppose the same is true for the far rights in other countries such as Germany and Italy. And this why we would not call these kind of far-right parties "reactionary", I think

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I 100% agree about the fact that far right parties still have (very) old fashioned views on security/immigration/national identity. Just that factually, Zemmour is not nostalgic of the Napoleonian empire (his campaign clip was mimicking de Gaulle's 18th of June 1940 speech), and saying that far right values are based on the middle-age's is far too much of a stretch

Comment: @Aserre From the interviews of him, and the comments about his views on societal issues such as feminism, etc. I feel that overall we can say he regrets Napoleonic France, although I acknowledge heard him regretting De Gaulle too. But this is not really the point of my question (I edited my post).

Comment: Concerning the (reactionary) far right values, I am referring to groups such as the GUD, the Action Française, but also Italian fascism and German nazism.

Comment: @Aserre I modified the passage on the middle ages into "of the pre-Enlightenment Europe"

Comment: I would distinguish between "reactionary" and "nostalgic". The actual meaning is"opposing change", but that is different from "wanting to change *back* to a previous older state". A Russian who wants to go back to "Communism" (as in USSR) isn't being reactionary, even though the same belief would have been reactionary in the time of Yeltsin and the end of the USSR.

Comment: The assertion for this question seems to be that capitalism started with the concept of bartering itself. This is not universally agreed upon, especially by those who think outside of the capitalist box (not necessarily communist). An assertion that communists want to to back to hunter-gatherer society comes across as a reductio ad absurdum. Secondly "[this] is an example of anarcho-communism" should not be rephrased as "communists want exactly [this] and nothing else" - which is what you're implicitly asserting with your mention of Pierre Clastres.

Answer (score 26):

The definition of "reactionary" in political context is "opposing political change or reform". People perceiving themselves as "reactionary" usually see the previosly-existing status quo as preferrable to the result of reform their opponents propose - note that what they perceive as "pre-existing status quo" may sometimes not be the only interpretation of the situation or even far removed in time from current moment (for example, [monarchists in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Fran%C3%A7aise). Good *old* times indeed). So while you may perceive European conservatives' intentions as a regression to the Middle Ages - they, in their own view, want the world to stop changing, and see any reform as dangerous, destabilising process with uncertain results threatening their established comfort.

On the other hand, communists and anarchists (within context of current European politics) are pro-change - they are unsatisfied with status quo (again, perception of what the status quo is may differ from person to person), and push for reform. Thus, in this context they are not a reactionary force.

P.S. What the reactonary politicians push for is not really "the good old times", but rather their own perception of "the good old times", which might be very... unconventional. For example,  Éric Zemmour, who you mentioned in your question, [is quoted](https://www.france24.com/en/france/20210913-%C3%A9ric-zemmour-the-far-right-pundit-who-threatens-to-outflank-le-pen) calling himself "a [Gaullist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaullism) and a [Bonapartist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonapartism)" - I personally have no idea where these two sets are supposed to intersect.

Comment: "I personally have no idea where these two sets are supposed to intersect." Not a specialist of Zemmour here, but would say that, from his point of view, France was then both great and united internally, and wanted to unite other countries to its project. "they, in their own view, want the world to stop changing" Really? Wikipedia says they want to return back "In political science, a reactionary or a reactionist is a person who holds political views that favor a return to the status quo ante", and that's also the discourse of Zemmour

Comment: @Starckman "before" is a poorly-defined term in this definition. Historically speaking, here's no need for the change to actually take place for reaction to form - good examples would be [Russian Empire during the rule of Alexander III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_III_of_Russia) or [the second Red Scare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthyism) in early 1950s USA. So status quo just as well can be "right now" or "near future" - the point is that the perception that there's a stable system and "evil left" want to destroy it exists.

Comment: Here it says “status quo ante”. I think your description concerns more the conservatives, who indeed want to maintain the “status quo”, or at least change as slow as possible (see the English Burke and Scruton)

Comment: @Starckman I think you take the definitions far too literally. For reaction, action is necessary - Burke's conservatism is also one form of such reaction, for the French Revolution. The mildest possible one. On the other end of the scale - the [Vendée Revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_the_Vend%C3%A9e).

Comment: Fyi : as a french citizen, gaullism doesn't mean anything anymore. Many politician uses De Gaulle's name to justify their ideas, even if they're completly out of what De Gaulle might have done, probably without understanding it themselves.

In a sense, it reminds me of Metal Gear Solid and all that "The Boss Legacy" non-sense.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I feel what your answer conveys the point of view of the communists and the anarcho-communists. Some reactionary far rights don't see themselves as reactionary neither, and have the rhetoric of wanting change and reforms, but that doesn't encompass them from being true reactionary

Comment: Does anyone actually see themselves as "reactionary"? I've always understood it as a word made up and used as a quasi-insult by their political opponents.

Comment: The intersection of Bonapartist & Gaulist, along with his own complaints of "Great Replacement" tell me that he yearns to return to an era where France was strong enough to invade others, be immune from invasion, and was totally white in skin color.

Comment: @T.E.D. You're not wrong but some people 'reclaim' it these days. Definitions like the one being upvoted here are so patently wrong—monarchists very much want to fully change the world in many many more ways than an Eastern European communist—it creates some leeway to fill in the vacuum with nonsense.

Comment: @lly - Yeah for me ... its a term from the mid-modern era best applied to people who wanted to keep the Franchise (the % of citizens allowed to vote, and the practical power given to those voters) down to the low levels they were currently at whenever liberalizing movements got popular. I know people in the 60's commonly used it to mean anyone against social progress of any kind (a fairly different meaning, although in some ways not). Today, I'm not sure it means anything. Not sure its worth putting that into an answer though, outside of the History site.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's a cudgel to hit enemies with (or here... I guess... confuse or provoke them) so it's on topic. It's just the OP in this case has such a bad grasp on the basics of the subject and seems to be actively avoiding improving their understanding that it might be worth voting to close this time around just for the sake of everyone's blood pressure.

Comment: @lly - Not saying its not on topic. Due to the adversarial nature of politics, there are rather a lot of political terms that are now way more useful as cudgels than in any descriptive capacity. Its perfectly reasonable for someone hearing one to wonder what the heck that really means, and to come here to ask.

Comment: @Starckman As to your response to _"they, in their own view, want the world to stop changing"_: For that comment to make sense, you need to make a distinction between undoing a change and introducing a new change. Yes, one can argue that the act of undoing a change is in and of itself introducing a change, but that very much depends on whether you've already accepted the "new normal" or not. Conservatives have not. Their baseline is still at the "old normal", and in their mind they are not _making_ a change, they're **undoing** one. Communists, however, push for an innovation, not a regression

Answer (score 18):

In the 90s of post-Soviet Russia, the liberal reformer strata did see the remaining communist sympathizers as reactionary.

The same was likely true of the views on "traditional" Maoists in the reforming China of 80s and 90s.

The mainstream political discourse is silent about this, but the countries of Eastern Block did have a significant number of people with sympathy to socialist times and disregard for the new, market and EU-oriented times; these were also seen as reactionaries by their new governments. This is apparent in East Germany where those sentiments led to creation of some political parties.

It's just that most Western countries did not have communist past so any Western communists are not reactionary by definition.

As a related example, Russian conservatives are also a questionable term since there's actually nothing left for them to conserve.

Comment: "It's just that most Western countries did not have communist past so any Western communists are not reactionary by definition." But they want to come back to their hunter-gatherer past!

Comment: They did not have a clear chain of succession pointing to such past. Maybe hunter-gatherer regimes existed sometime, somewhere, but there were nothing which could be called "Western European political hunter gatherers".

Comment: This is indirectly related to a core difference between communism and right-wing ideologies, right-wing ideologies make a strong emphasis on the group identity, while communism does not (it is deemed universal, humanist, international). Still, there is the goal to come back to a previous state

Comment: Only a small subset of communists really want to come back to previous state; most of them want to advance to the next state or at least go sideways.

Comment: *The mainstream political discourse is silent about this* — no it isn't? At least in Germany *Ostalgie* and more politically in-depth versions of the same get significant attention in the mainstream media (moreso in the 1990s than today, but it was more prevalent then).

Comment: @gerrit I imagine that other ex-Warsaw pact countries also have this phenomenon, but we do not hear about it outside of the Eastern German context. I witnessed it personally in Montenegro where some obituaries carry a red star taking place of religious affiliation (!)

Comment: @Starckman Again, no, they don't. Even in classical Marxism, the goal was never a return to prelapsarian Eden. It's to advance to a postindustrial New Jerusalem. If you're going to plug wax in your ears and ignore that basic truth, it's probably better to just close the question.

Answer (score 18):

No apart from maybe [primitivsts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitivism) and [anarcho-primitivsts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-primitivism) these groups do NOT want to go back to living as hunter gatherers.

And in general viewing "primitive" societies as an ideal to strive for is pretty novel. For the most part when people looked at it they saw a lack of everything and usually reacted with disgust. Like the term "primitive" usually has a very negative connotation and was regularly used to justify colonialism and exploitation by the more "civilized" societies.

Hobbes et al apparently even went so far to describe the "state of nature" (so his idea of primitive societies) as a war man against man and that only the absolute monarchy and the submission to a leviathan has provided them with peace and order.

There had been counter ideas of a "noble savage" and as civilization as corrupting element, but either way people were more or less guessing what live before history must have been like and their encounter with "humans living in the wild" was usually not characterized by a genuine inquiry of a different but equally valuable way of life, but usually as an opportunity to exploit and subjugate and to see oneself as superior to others.

Recently talks about that might become more relevant given that our economy has reached scales where it's destructive rather than constructive, exploitation, toxicity and waste and the climate change that is going to effect us negatively for a long time and can get worse the more we push it. So models of sustainable existence might take examples from what we previously insulted as primitive.

That being said at the time when these ideologies emerged primitive societies were far away (both physically and in terms of being pre-historic with no accurate idea of how things actually worked back then) and especially Marx et al were not a fan of that. On the contrary Marx even praised capitalism for being way more efficient than it's predecessors and saw it as a necessary stage of development. Oversimplified he looked at society as one interconnected system and basically argued that this system needs labor to reproduce it's state of existence. If you spend 24 hours a day of work and regeneration to produce food for the next day than you're running in circles, if you produce more than that you're free to spend part of the next day doing something else.

So the collective labor and the development of more capable means of production was seen as a necessity for the surplus economy and thus a necessity for human liberation. No longer a slave to nature but a master of ones own life.

So the criticism of the economic system is that the energy that is expended in pursuit of the advancement of that system is often disproportionate to the outcome. So lots of people make it run and run faster with their labor, but few people extract ever more benefits from it. So despite the technical ability to improve the conditions and to liberate people, they get further enslaved to pay for the privilege of the few.

So the idea is how could one reorganize society so that one doesn't loose all these benefits of collective production, but achieve a society of equals where freedom is universal and not a privilege.

You can idealize a hunter-gatherer society to something like that, but usually a society of scarcity develops different socio-economic characteristics than one without it. So not sure you can compare them.

On the other hand right wing reactionary movements usually aim for a particular period in the rather recent time. Like if you go beyond folklore and cosplay nonsense the middle ages weren't all that great, cities being permeated with the smell of feces, no sewage, no internet, not even newspapers or books in quantity and availability. An aristocracy that feasted while a peasantry that struggled from harvest to harvest, wars, rape, pillages. So the further you go back in time, usually the less appealing it's going to be, so you usually aim for that sweet spot of nostalgia of idk 20-50 years ago (or just a few years further back so something that your parents marveled about but which you've never seen in person and thus believe to be larger than life and of a perfection that you can't imagine). Something that people can relate to. Something that you might have admired as a kid before your adult self peeked behind the curtain and was less than impressed.

That might be nonetheless mythological and often enough conservatives and reactionaries aim to preserve or restore something that never was to begin with but which they just imagined as such, but they nonetheless have a concrete idea of something that they think was like that in the rather recent past.

So it might happen that ones communism or anarcho-communism are achieved somewhere people end up being conservative when they defend it against changes or reactionary when they try to get it back after having failed.

Though given that ideally communism and anarchism aren't really concrete systems but rather modes of operation, similar to how a democracy isn't prescribing what should be done or how it should be done, but merely that whatever is done should have it's legitimization by the people rather than by the whim of a monarch, it's probably different to defend that vs defending the privileged rule of a particular party or person.

Like it's easier to prevent "the wrong person" to be in power, than to prevent anybody from being in power. It's a constant struggle between empowering the individual slave to be an equal participant without having them enslave others with their power. That is quite a different beast over just exercising power and fending off adversaries.

Comment: "but merely that whatever is done should have it's legitimization by the people rather than by the whim of a monarch" this is democracy, the separation of powers, the rule of law, etc. so classical liberalism, not communism. Communism is first a dictatorship, and then a return to a free-class society (similar to that of the hunter-gatherers), anarcho-communism is the same thing, without dictatorship in-between. In both cases, there is a preliminary more or less violent revolution, either by the policiticized workers in the case of communism, or by the masses in the case of anarcho-communism

Comment: @Starckman As stated in the answer, there is no "return to". These people didn't know how a hunter-gatherer society looked like and they didn't want to go back to one. That's simply a mischaracterization. And "communism" is first of all that collective ownership of the means of production by a society of equals. The dictatorship of the proletariat as opposed to the dictatorship of the bourgeoisie without universal suffrage that "democracy" claim is a little stale, was seen a means to an end not a goal in itself. Also separation of power largely became relevant due to a lack of that: president

Comment: "And "communism" is first of all that collective ownership of the means of production by a society of equals" This is similar to the society of the hunter-gatherers, according to an anarcho-communist, anthropologist specialist of the hunter-gatherers (see my post). "was seen a means to an end not a goal in itself" agree, did not say the contrary. The separation of power was theorized before there was any president. And there a separation of power in many countries were there is no president (Belgium, England, to cite a few)

Comment: "but merely that whatever is done should have it's legitimization by the people" Or it is direct universal suffrage, but this is not communism, this is direct universal suffrage.

Comment: "This is similar to the society of the hunter-gatherers, according to an anarcho-communist, anthropologist specialist". First of all the people you cite largely lived prior to anthropologists deserving that title. And I guess that's more of a refute of the omnipresent "it's against human nature to not divide into slaves and masters", which it apparently isn't. But that doesn't mean that one wants to go back to that situation, not to mention that the similarity is superficial as the economic conditions have vastly different social implication. Non-stationary societies, size, distribution etc.

Comment: The book where the anthropologist makes the point was published in 1974. Anthropology did not exist in 1974?

Comment: @Starckman 2/ A president is just a term for a head of state, it's literally the French word for "chairman" which can include all sorts of heads of states. And the separation of powers often developed out of necessity to curb the power of the head of state by splitting it in different entities, though it's necessity is most apparent where it's absent, so if the government is one person who has legislative and executive privileges that is more relevant than if it's organized in a parliament or direct democracy where you have less concentration of power to begin with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147124/discussion-between-haxor789-and-starckman).

Comment: This is the right answer because it actually speaks to the original meaning of the terms. Communism is (in most places) not "reactionary" because there is not an actual prior state of communism to revert to; while there are some egalitarian traditional cultures, their politics don't (or didn't) bear any relationship to "workers owning the means of production", because they don't (or didn't) have the concept of an organized labour force, or of "production" qua a society-wide measurable objective, in the first place.

Comment: @Starckman "Communism is first a dictatorship, and then a return to a free-class society (similar to that of the hunter-gatherers)"... Your "similar" is doing so much heavy lifting there, it's already been pancaked and is on a beeline to the center of the earth. No, there is no part of classical Marxism (let alone Leninism, Stalinism, or any phase of Chinese Communism) where the classless society is in any sense back to hunting and gathering. That's a _capitalist_ fetish that there's no way to have an industrial society along any other lines than its own.

Comment: @lly I think the point would be to show simply in which way the new society proposed by Marx is different from that of the hunter-gatherers; instead of some people in the comments repeating that I don't understand what Marxism is or plugged wax in my ears. The people who did described something described something extremely abstract which, in essence, doesn't seem to have a lot of difference with hunter-gatherers society

Comment: @Starckman Eh? You mean aside from the lack of hunting; the lack of gathering; the lack of family/clan being the sole criteria of personal morality and allegiance; the introductions of (at minimum) education, organization, and communication structures entirely alien to primitive humanity and their effects on individuals and society; and the  fundamental point that Marx is vague precisely because the crux of his 'insight' is a historical dialectic that economic and social realities shape human morality and intellect to the point that he (living within capitalism) knew he couldn't (cont.)

Comment: precisely see what the outcome of the historical dialectic would be on the other side of the coming revolution? Aside from that? Well... I mean, yeah, aside from all that it might be rather similar in that there would be some level of humans existing and some level of reproduction occurring and probably some level of wearing clothings, eating, and sleeping. Those bits you're handwaving are kinda the entire core of Marxism, though, which is why your responses have provoked some confusion/eyerolling.

Comment: Thank you for tackling my remark. “Marx is vague” here it points to another important problem with Marxism, which is that it calls for a revolution putting everything down (while Marx himself recognized that capitalism brought a lot of significant positive changes) for the sake for a project which is not clearly defined. Don’t you think that is problematic?

Comment: The fact that the project is a bet on a speculation of one mind (Hegel and its dialectic) does not make it less creepy, in the contrary.

Answer (score 6):

This is a language question rather than a political one.

Simply put, words do not necessarily correlate with their etymology or even with definitions people give them. Although, the word reactionary seems to evoke the idea of "return to the past" and some poor definitions may define it as such, that is not what it actually means in common language.

In common language, reactionary refers to a specific right-wing idea of returning to an idealized, more conservative past in the face of some concluded social or political reforms.

Why it came to mean that is an interesting question to consider, but it is more likely just coincidence. Perhaps it was first coined for people like this so has generally been applied to similar people. According to Wikipedia, the term was popularized after the French Revolution to refer to those who wanted to revert the reforms.

Another possible explanation is that reactionary refers to a return to a "close" past in some sense rather than something from prehistory. This can explain why it may refer to people who want a return of communism in Eastern Block countries. However, I do not think this is a correct explanation.

More likely, the word simply shifted meaning in those countries. As for in normal English, I do not expect people to call communist sympathizers in previously communist countries reactionaries, because the term has a right-wing connotation.

Comment: The words didn't change or shift. OP is simply misunderstanding their meaning.

Answer (score 4):

A rubric I've often used to explain this is to note that the political spectrum is a lot like the is/ought problem in philosophy. Specifically:

- Conservative think that the way the social world *is* (or at least *was* in recent memory) is good, and resist efforts to move away from it
- Progressives think that the way the social world *ought to be* (ideally or pragmatically) is good, and push away from what *is/was* to achieve that goal

  - (note that I'm avoiding the term 'liberal' here, because it's confusing in this context)

This is subject to degrees, from moderates (who are not committed to the status quo or to societal ideals) through conventional conservatives and progressives (who have varied interests and agendas) to extremists in both directions.

Reactionaries are conservative extremists, defined by the fact that they pick a specific point in human history and define it as the ultimate Good. Sometimes this point is remote, sometimes it's mythologized, sometimes it's entirely imaginary, but from the reactionary perspective it is a concrete point in past human history that society must return to. Even the name indicates that: they are reacting against a present-day movement away from that historical moment of achieved Good.

Progressive extremists, by contrast, are generally referred to as revolutionaries, defined by the fact that they pick some never-before-achieved (thus future) point as the pinnacle of human Good. They generally want to strip away historical forms of human society which they see as mere impediments to societal growth. This is true even of anarcho-primitivists: they do not idealize or want to return to a primitive world (with its disease, hunger, exposure, etc), but instead idealize the loose social organization of primitive peoples and want to integrate that into an advanced technological world.

Reactionaries and revolutionaries share two common traits:

- They idealize a moment in human history as ultimately Good (though the moments they idealize are far, far separated)
- They can be aggressive, even violent, in their pursuit of that idealized Good

But that's the end of it.

And yes, it can be confusing if we do not keep perspective in mind. For instance, it's easy as an outsider to understand that (say) the Aryan rulership of the German Nazi Party was completely fabricated: Aryan rulership as described never *actually* existed at any concrete point in human history, and thus the Nazis could *look* like revolutionaries pursuing a novel future ideal. But from within Nazism, Aryan rulership was taken as an unquestionable and factual truth — a concrete point is remote human history — and Nazism pursued it as a return, not as a progression. That's what makes them reactionary.

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarification of the people you say see Communism/AnarchoCommunism as non-reactionary being "the public":
They do. Not all obviously, but especially in the west.
Reactionary opinions and stances on policy and social issues is generally associated with the right, and for good reason.
Oxford Languages Defines Reactionary: *opposing political or social progress or reform*

Reactionism is only reactionary from the view of progress: If the reaction opposes the progress it is "Reactionary", and not just a reaction.

Historically, the left (including the economic philosophy of Kropotkin, Marx, Engels, etc.) is generally on the progress side.
(Hence "Progressive" being negatively associated with the left and communism.)
Wikipedia: *In the United States, communism is widely used as a pejorative term as part of a Red Scare, much like socialism, and mainly in reference to authoritarian socialism and Communist states.*

Thus your hypothesis is at least noticing the reason:
The left does indeed stress the forward march of progress, and so when a NEW policy is put in place, it is generally REACTED to, whereas the abolition of OLD policies could be thought of as generally being related to progress.

This is obviously not always true - some old policies are still progressive, and are being removed even now, and by people on the right at that - and my answer is not necessarily based on pure fact, but also on anecdotes, to feel free to correct me as you see fit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Curiously, *Progressives/Progressists* was a German political party in the times of Marx, which represented Bourgeosie, as opposed to the governing aristocracy. Obviously they were opposed by Marx, and when Lassalle established the Labor party, he was seeking an alliance with the aristocracy against the Progressists - hoping to bring Socialism/Communism via parliamentary means. (This was obviously opposed by Marx, for whom the state was inherently evil, and the only way to progerss was violent revolution.)

Comment: @RogerVadim Good point.
However Marx did not think that the only way to progress was through a violent revolution.
The revolution that Marxism calls for is only necessarily violent insofar as the destruction of private property and assets of the Bourgeoise.

Comment: Marx called for the *complete destruction of the existing social and economic order* - this is a lot more than just private property, more like *our way of life* in modern language. And as a method he proposed the *dictatorship of the proletariat* - a period where all the other classes would be deprived of their rights, while their way of life is destroyed - this includes peasants, small business, intellectual, the lumpenproletariat (i.e., the poor), etc. Though Marx himself admitted that in practice it would mean the dictatorship by a small group of communists.

Comment: That's still not necessarily violence towards the bourgeoise.
If you destroy the exploitative ability of a class of people, you are not harming them.
It can only be seen as harm is we were to attack physically the body of the upper class, like in the Soviet establishment.
Harm against property and way of life of the oppressor should not be a crime in the service of the oppressed.